# how to set enableHistoryDatabase for GetHistoryForKey() in docker

Tags: docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I'm working with fabric and want to use gethistoryforkey api return the history of key values,but  it only return current value.I find that  enablehistorydatabase is required.can i set it in docker-compose.yaml

Comment: History should be enabled by default.  Which version of Fabric are you using and where did you get your docker-compose files from?

Comment: @GariSingh thank you. I have solved it. just add `- CORE_LEDGER_HISTORY_ENABLEHISTORYDATABASE=true`  in  docker-compose files

Comment: Glad to hear.  It's interesting because by default it should be enabled.